# START_PAGE only makes the header for the first page

Tags: asp.net, .net, itext7

I have this code for web development:

```
protected internal class MyEventHandler : iText.Kernel.Events.IEventHandler
{
    public virtual void HandleEvent(iText.Kernel.Events.Event @event)
    {
        iText.Kernel.Events.PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = 
                (iText.Kernel.Events.PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
    }

    public void onStartPage(
        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer, iText.Layout.Document document)
    {
        // paragragrap for start pages
        …
    }
}
```

…

```
MyEventHandler StartPage = new MyEventHandler();
pdf.AddEventHandler(iText.Kernel.Events.PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new MyEventHandler());
StartPage.onStartPage(writer, document);
```

And other code that adds more to the page.
It only makes the header for the first page.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing event handling from different iText versions.

In iText 5 you used to implement `IPdfPageEvent`, often by extending `PdfPageEventHelper`, and here you had separate methods like

```
void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
```

etc.

In iText 7 you implement `IEventHandler` which has only a single method,

```
void HandleEvent(Event @event)
```

You either register your event handler only for one event type and, consequentially, know in `HandleEvent` that the right event arrived, or you determine based on the event type (`@event.GetEventType()`) which type of event you got and execute the appropriate code.

#### An example event listener changing page rotation

E.g. in [this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i7js-highlevel/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel/chapter07/C07E01_EventHandlers.java) the event handler is registered for page starts only

```
C07E01_EventHandlers.PageRotationEventHandler eventHandler = new PageRotationEventHandler();
pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler);
```

and in its event handling method acts accordingly

```
public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
    docEvent.GetPage().Put(PdfName.Rotate, this.rotation);
}
```

The full example class:

```
public class C07E01_EventHandlers {
    public const String DEST = "../../../results/chapter07/jekyll_hyde_page_orientation.pdf";

    public static readonly PdfNumber PORTRAIT = new PdfNumber(0);

    public static readonly PdfNumber LANDSCAPE = new PdfNumber(90);

    public static readonly PdfNumber INVERTEDPORTRAIT = new PdfNumber(180);

    public static readonly PdfNumber SEASCAPE = new PdfNumber(270);

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
        file.Directory.Create();
        new C07E01_EventHandlers().CreatePdf(DEST);
    }

    public virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        pdf.GetCatalog().SetPageLayout(PdfName.TwoColumnLeft);
        C07E01_EventHandlers.PageRotationEventHandler eventHandler = new PageRotationEventHandler();
        pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler);
        Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A8);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Dr. Jekyll"));
        eventHandler.SetRotation(INVERTEDPORTRAIT);
        document.Add(new AreaBreak());
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Mr. Hyde"));
        eventHandler.SetRotation(LANDSCAPE);
        document.Add(new AreaBreak());
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Dr. Jekyll"));
        eventHandler.SetRotation(SEASCAPE);
        document.Add(new AreaBreak());
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Mr. Hyde"));
        document.Close();
    }

    protected internal class PageRotationEventHandler : IEventHandler {
        protected internal PdfNumber rotation = C07E01_EventHandlers.PORTRAIT;

        public virtual void SetRotation(PdfNumber orientation) {
            this.rotation = orientation;
        }

        public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
            docEvent.GetPage().Put(PdfName.Rotate, this.rotation);
        }

        internal PageRotationEventHandler() {
        }
    }
}
```

#### An example page listener adding headers and footers

In comments you asked for an *example for header and not rotation a page*. For that look e.g. at the [iText 7 Jump-Start Tutorial](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-java) chapter 3 ([Using renderers and event handlers](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-java/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers)) example `C03E03_UFO` ([Java version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i7js-jumpstart/develop/src/main/java/tutorial/chapter03/C03E03_UFO.java) / [C# version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i7ns-samples/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.jumpstart/tutorial/chapter03/C03E03_UFO.cs)) in which an event listener is used to add a background, a watermark, a header, and a footer:

```
public class C03E03_UFO {

    internal static PdfFont helvetica = null;

    internal static PdfFont helveticaBold = null;

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        helvetica = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
        helveticaBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        ...
    }

    protected internal virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) {
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new C03E03_UFO.MyEventHandler(this));
        ...
    }

    ...

    protected internal class MyEventHandler : IEventHandler {
        public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
            int pageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);
            Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
            //Set background
            Color limeColor = new DeviceCmyk(0.208f, 0, 0.584f, 0);
            Color blueColor = new DeviceCmyk(0.445f, 0.0546f, 0, 0.0667f);
            pdfCanvas.SaveState()
                     .SetFillColor(pageNumber % 2 == 1 ? limeColor : blueColor)
                     .Rectangle(pageSize.GetLeft(), pageSize.GetBottom(), pageSize.GetWidth(), pageSize.GetHeight())
                     .Fill()
                     .RestoreState();
            //Add header and footer
            pdfCanvas.BeginText()
                     .SetFontAndSize(C03E03_UFO.helvetica, 9)
                     .MoveText(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2 - 60, pageSize.GetTop() - 20)
                     .ShowText("THE TRUTH IS OUT THERE")
                     .MoveText(60, -pageSize.GetTop() + 30)
                     .ShowText(pageNumber.ToString())
                     .EndText();
            //Add watermark
            iText.Layout.Canvas canvas = new iText.Layout.Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, page.GetPageSize());
            canvas.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
            canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, UnitValue.CreatePointValue(60));
            canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT, C03E03_UFO.helveticaBold);
            canvas.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"), 298, 421, pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page), TextAlignment.
                CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
            pdfCanvas.Release();
        }

        internal MyEventHandler(C03E03_UFO _enclosing) {
            this._enclosing = _enclosing;
        }

        private readonly C03E03_UFO _enclosing;
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking that example listens to `PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE` instead of `PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE`. That difference shouldn't hurt too much, though.

Comment: In Stateless programming (i.e. asp.net ) something like C07E01_EventHandlers does not exist.
Please, can you write the example for header and not rotation a page.
Avi

Comment: public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
            docEvent.GetPage().Put(PdfName.Rotate, this.rotation);
        }

Comment: This does not work if I want to Add Paragrph. Please help.